# Parse comments in XML in Android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, saxparser

For my personal purposes I'd like to parse comments in Android Manifest file. In these comments there can be tags with attributes and values that I want to extract. It is similar to  tag in html files that is usually commented because some browsers does not support this tag. So I want to implement similar things in android manifest.

I know that in Android manifest file is parsed using SAXParser. Moreover, I think I should use LexicalHandler for this purposes but I've never faced before with this functionality and I want to know how to do this. Code snippets and any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. I was thinking about this but I was not sure. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm entirely sure that you cannot parse the raw XML Manifest, because like everything that is in the `res` folder (except `res/raw`), the manifest is compiled and stored in a binary format, so the comments are removed.

Maybe you can play with xmlns and capture the manifest parsing... But I doubt it, the Manifest is interpreted by the package manager, and I don't think that you can have access to it.

**The solution (from your feedbacks):**
The requested feature is impossible, because during the compilation all comments from AndroidManifest file are removed.

You can check this in the following way:

1. Create a simple app project (Hello World) and add comments in your AndroidManifest file.
2. Compile project and export an .apk file (signed or unsigned).
3. Using tools like apktool or similar extract your apk file.
4. Check the result in AndroidManifest.xml - there are no comments.

You should try to find other way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible as the AndroidManifest is not available as a classpath resource.  The only way I can think of is to actually make a copy of the AndroidManifest.xml into your source files and have it built as a compiled object using an ant target

Then you just access it like a normal XML file using the XML APIs.

Comment: I'm working on the framework layer so I can parse AndroidManifest. The only problem that I do not know how to do this. I think it can be considered as a simple xml file but I need to know how to extract tags and their attributes from comments. Moreover, there can be several comments in the Manifest file, that's why I need tags.

Comment: Understood, but the XML file is not present in the classpath during runtime (unless you make it exist by making a copy)

Comment: What do you mean? Imagine that you have a Package Installer. It parses AndroidManifest file and represents the information to a user. So on this level I guess I can parse this xml file. Or maybe I do not understand something because actually I've never faced closely with xml parsing.

Comment: If you want to read a file at runtime you have a few options: you know where the actual file is on the filesystem e.g. new File("/etc/passwd") or you get it from the classpath Thread.getContextClassLoader().getResource("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF").

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be *that guy*, but you should probably maintain your custom XML in /assets/ and not overload the manifest.xml file.